# Como adicionar conteúdo a uma textview sem ter de copiar o que já há nela?

Tags: android, textview

Galera é o seguinte. Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar um parágrafo ou uma única palavra a uma textview que já contém conteúdo sem necessariamente copiar o que já tem nela. Gostaria que me mostrassem algo que servisse para qualquer texto.

Um exemplo do que quero exatamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a checkbox está marcada o texto exibido é "Neo está". Do contrário "Neo não está".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A medida que clico no botão "+1" desejo que seja adicionado após o conteúdo já existente na textview (Neo está/Neo não está) o status correspondente ao valor da variável cont.

Se cont == 1 => **texto já existente** + solteiro.
Se cont == 2 => **texto já existente** + namorando.
Se cont == 3 => **texto já existente** + casado.

```js
package genesysgeneration.wwww;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView tv01;
    private Button btnMais1;
    private int cont=0;
    private CheckBox cbNeo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);

        addCheckBoxCondiction();

        addComplementText();

        btnMais1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
        btnMais1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void addCheckBoxCondiction(){

        cbNeo=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbNeo);
        cbNeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    tv01.setText(String.valueOf("Neo está"));

                }else{

                    tv01.setText(String.valueOf("Neo não está"));

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void addComplementText(){

        if(cont==1){

            //tv01 => texto já existente + solteiro

        }

        if(cont==2){

            //tv01 => texto já existente + namorando

        }

        if(cont==3){

            //tv01 => texto já existente + casado

        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        cont+=1;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView tv;

tv.setText(
    tv.getText().toString() +
    "seu novo texto"
);
```

Não entendi se é exatamente isso que você precisa, mas dessa forma você vai concatenar a String que já está dentro da TextView com o seu texto novo.

Particularmente, não acho essa a solução mais elegante, eu te recomendo fazer alguma classe de formatação que receba alguns inputs padrão e geram o texto pra você, porque no longo prazo essa estratégia atual fica mais dificil de dar manutencao.

Comment: Isso é exatamente isso que quero fazer. Desejo realizar a concatenação dessa String.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso se era isso que vc precisava, aceite a resposta pra que no futuro outras pessoas saibam que essa eh a solucao.